# Why can't my C program complete the code after inputing a number?

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I just started learning C so I have no idea why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int x);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Enter a number");
    int userNum;
    scanf("%d", &userNum);
    int result = square(userNum);
    printf("The result is %d", result);

}

int square(int x){
    int result = x*x;
    return result;
}
```

It would ask for a number but then nothing would happen after I input. If I were to take the scanf out and put `square(10)` or something, the code will run and finish.

Comment: Why is this tagged java?

Comment: If it's a C program, why is your question tagged C++ *AND* Java?

Comment: Can you give us some example input you've given to this program?

Comment: result variable in square function is useless. just return x*x. And your main() function must return int value.

Comment: Did you hit enter after you typed in your number?

Comment: I tagged the first things that came to my mind. Those comments really did help me thank you. Why does that matter?

Comment: It matters because those tags are irrelevant to your question. If everybody put irrelevant tags on their questions, it would render the tag system useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles and runs as expected for me using both `gcc` and `clang`... to make it more clear (as maybe other text is getting in your way of seeing the answer) add new lines to what you are outputting to `stdout`:

```
int main( void ) {
    printf("Enter a number: ");

    int userNum;

    scanf("%d", &userNum);

    int result = square(userNum);

    printf("\nThe result is: %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

If you are testing in terminal (and not piping input) then recall that `scanf` (with the `%d` placeholder) will read an integer until the next character that is not a numerical character. So on your keyboard you will need to type 10 and return (or enter). Otherwise, pipe your program an input file:

```
10
```

... using the following command:

```
./a.out < input.txt
```

Comment: Okay, I got it to work through terminal but it still doesn't work as expected in xcode. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your main function says that the return type is "**int**" , but you are not returning any value.

Just add a statement return 0 at just before the last closing braces of the main function.

It should work fine.
Here is the same program and it works fine.

http://ideone.com/H3Izqh

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int x);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Enter a number");
    int userNum;
    scanf("%d", &userNum);
    int result = square(userNum);
    printf("\nThe result is %d", result);
    return 0;   //NOTICE THIS STATEMENT
}

int square(int x){
    int result = x*x;
    return result;
}
```